# Add column to table and set all row's values for the column to a specified value

Tags: php, mysql, alter

I have a SQL database table I need to add a column to. Once that column is added I need to give all rows a one-time specified value for the added column;
I know to add the column I could use the following:

```
// Adds a column to the table
"ALTER TABLE myTable ADD lastCheck INT;"
```

From here I'm left with looping through a 15+k row table using php. Is there a better/faster way to do this without having to depend on PHP as the work horse?

A few notes:
1: After the initial setting of the column row's value, values can be null, so specifying a default is out of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD lastCheck INT DEFAULT 10
```

OR you can run an update afterward

```
UPDATE MyTable SET lastCheck = 10
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6df6e/1)

Comment: This will only set row's values for the column that are added after the creation of the column.

Comment: Yes. Hence why I made the comment. Rows before the column is added aren't getting updated to the specified default value.

Comment: Yes sorry... since it is nullable column it wont set value. I was thinking of equivalent of ALTER TABLE myTable ADD lastCheck INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 10

Answer (score 2):

You Can use:

```
$query="Update Tablename set Columnname='value'";
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN lastCheck INT DEFAULT 123
```

This will add new column and set that column value for all records at once to 123.
This will not prohibit for this column to have NULL value.
Actually, you can even set default to be NULL after doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN lastCheck DROP DEFAULT
```

Comment: as stated in codingbiz's comments. this doesn't update rows that were added before the column was.

Comment: well, if it is old **er**  you should have mentioned the version number in the question.